# Checking for Unique Key and updating row or creating a new one WordPress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a draggable div in which the position is being saved to database with user_id set to unique. How would I check if user_id exists.. and if it does, update the other 3 columns.. If it does not exist, insert new row. I have read to use "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE", but having a hard time implementing it. Any thoughts?

As explained by @N.B. - Working solution

```
global $wpdb;

    $_POST['user_id'];
    $_POST['div_id'];
    $_POST['x_pos'];
    $_POST['y_pos'];

    $user_id    = $_POST['user_id'];
    $div_id     = $_POST['div_id'];
    $x_pos      = $_POST['x_pos'];
    $y_pos      = $_POST['y_pos'];

$wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare(" INSERT INTO coords

   (user_id, div_id, x_pos, y_pos)
    VALUES (%d, %s, %d, %d)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    x_pos = VALUES(x_pos), y_pos = VALUES(y_pos)",

    $user_id,
    $div_id,
    $x_pos,
    $y_pos
    ));
```

Comment: I have edited the code above (for other users who may have the same question) to reflect the working code suggest by @true

Comment: You should have used `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`. The answer you accepted is incorrect.

Comment: @N.B. I tried to implement that method but did not work. If you say that the answer below is not working (which it is), then can you show a working example using ON DUPLICATE KEY? The answer provided below DOES in fact work..

Comment: Yes, it works because you're testing it as the only user. What happens if there are two requests done at the same time? Both will conclude that there's no such user and both will insert the data - and there's nothing to stop duplicating the data. That's why we use unique keys and that's why we let databases worry about data uniqueness, not PHP. Method is working if you don't test it properly, and it wasn't tested properly. Saying that `ON DUPLICATE KEY` doesn't work isn't helping, you must specify HOW it's not working (SQL syntax error, it doesn't update, blank page etc.).

Comment: @N.B. - Yes, it does work.. I have added the rest of the code above. AND "user_id" column is set to "unique"...

Comment: Do you know what concurrency is? Do you understand why I wrote that the code does not work **accurately** and do you understand that the code you are using and claiming that it works is actually coming with a huge bug - one that lets you duplicate data? If you do understand, why are you posting javascript code?

Comment: @N.B. - Well hey.. I am here looking for solutions if you're just going to SAY everything is wrong, YOU ARE no help. Can you OFFER anything besides saying "IT DOESNT WORK"? Example? Something a bit more intuitive? Or just be rude?

Comment: I'm not rude, I offered you an example. I even asked you what was wrong with `ON DUPLICATE KEY...` but you posted JS code. Am I supposed to beg you to tell me how to help you? I asked you what you don't understand but you opted to be cocky. I even told you that the method you used is not correct, I explained why and gave you an overview when it doesn't work. But, you didn't **read** and I can't make you do that. I can just hope that people who stumble upon the same problem will use their head before copy pasting the first posted solution.

Comment: @N.B. I have updated code above.. Is this what you were suggesting?

Comment: That's exactly it. Not only is it less code, you are also secure against multiple inserts occurring at the same time. Is that query working for you or is it failing?

Comment: @N.B. - You are exactly right. I just needed coffee, I suppose. All working correctly. Much appreciated!

Comment: I'm glad you got it working. Now we just need @true to modify his answer a bit so he can get an upvote for correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @N.B. pointed out in the comments, while the first method I submitted works, it is open to race conditions. I'd like to thank him for pointing that out. Here is that first solution with race conditions:

```
$user_exists = $wpdb->get_var(
    $wpdb->prepare("SELECT user_id FROM coords WHERE user_id = %d", $user_id)
);
if($user_exists) {
    // Do Update
}
else {
    // Do Insert
}
```

These race conditions are astronomical, as an insert must finish executing in the time between the first query returning and the next insert query. But the race condition exists none-the-less, and therefore could happen at some point in time.

However your database is still safe. When it occurs it won't duplicate the data, but rather it will throw a wpdb error that a unique key already exists and the insert will silently fail (it won't terminate the script and it won't output the error unless error reporting is turned on).

```
WordPress database error: [Duplicate entry '3' for key 'PRIMARY']
```

Amazingly, the above technique is used in the Wordpress core and by countless plugin and theme authors, and I could only find two instances of 'ON DUPLICATE' being used correctly in the Wordpress core. So a large chunk of the internet runs with multiple instances of this race condition seemingly just fine, just to give you an idea of the astronomical chance we're talking about.

**Regardless of the chance, to use it is bad practice.** As N.B. commented, *the database should worry about the data and not PHP.*

### The Real Solution

Wordpress, for whatever reason, does not have an 'INSERT ON DUPLICATE UPDATE' function, which means you have to either write up a query each time with $wpdb->query or build your own function to handle it. I went with writing a function because writing wpdb->query each time is a pain and brings the user one layer closer to accidental mysql injection. Also development speed.

```
/**
 * Insert on Duplicate Key Update.
 *
 * Wordpress does not have an 'insert on duplicate key update' function, which
 * forces user's to create their own or write standard queries. As writing
 * queries is annoying and open to mysql injection via human error, this function
 * automates this custom query in an indentical fashion to the core wpdb functions.
 * Source: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31150317/4248167
 *
 * @global wpdb $wpdb
 * @param string $table The table you wish to update.
 * @param array $data The row you wish to update or insert, using a field => value associative array.
 * @param array $where The unique keys that you want to update at or have inserted, also a field => value array.
 * @param array $data_formats Wordpress formatting array for the data. Will default to %s for every field.
 * @param array $where_formats Wordpress formatting array for the where. Will default to %s for every field.
 * @return boolean True if successfully inserted or updated the row.
 */
function insertOrUpdate($table, $data, $where, $data_formats = array(), $where_formats = array())
{
    if(!empty($data) && !empty($where)) {
        global $wpdb;
        // Data Formats - making sure they match up with the data.
        $default_data_format = (isset($data_formats[0])) ? $data_formats[0] : '%s';
        $data_formats = array_pad($data_formats, count($data), $default_data_format);
        $data_formats = array_splice($data_formats, 0, count($data));
        // Where Formats - making sure they match up with the where data.
        $default_where_format = (isset($where_formats[0])) ? $where_formats[0] : '%s';
        $where_formats = array_pad($where_formats, count($where), $default_where_format);
        $where_formats = array_splice($where_formats, 0, count($where));
        // Get Fields
        $data_fields = array_keys($data);
        $where_fields = array_keys($where);
        // Create Query
        $query =
            "INSERT INTO $table" .
            " (" . implode(', ', array_merge($data_fields, $where_fields)) . ")" .
            " VALUES(" . implode(', ', array_merge($data_formats, $where_formats)) . ")" .
            " ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE";
        // Compile update fields and add to query
        $field_strings = array();
        foreach($data_fields as $index => $data_field) {
            $field_strings[] = " $data_field = " . $data_formats[$index];
        }
        $query .= implode(', ', $field_strings);
        // Put it all together - returns true on successful update or insert 
        // and false on failure or if the row already matches the data.
        return !!$wpdb->query(
            $wpdb->prepare(
                $query,
                array_merge(
                    array_merge(
                        array_values($data),
                        array_values($where)
                    ),
                    array_values($data)
                )
            )
        );
    }
    return false;
}
```

To use it, you simply enter parameters just like you would with a $wpdb->update function call.

```
insertOrUpdate(
    'testing_table',
    array('column_a' => 'hello', 'column_b' => 'world'),
    array('id' => 3),
    array('%s', '%s'),
    array('%d')
);
```

In your case, it would be:

```
insertOrUpdate(
    'coords', 
    array('div_id' => $div_id, 'x_pos' => $x_pos, 'y_pos' => $y_pos), 
    array('user_id' => $user_id),
    array('%d', '%d', '%d'),
    array('%d')
);
```

Or you can just use a default formatting:

```
insertOrUpdate(
    'coords', 
    array('div_id' => $div_id, 'x_pos' => $x_pos, 'y_pos' => $y_pos), 
    array('user_id' => $user_id),
    array('%d')
);
```

Or you can ignore the formatting which will default to formatting as strings:

```
insertOrUpdate(
    'coords', 
    array('div_id' => $div_id, 'x_pos' => $x_pos, 'y_pos' => $y_pos), 
    array('user_id' => $user_id)
);
```

If you find any issues just let me know.

Comment: The update was formatted incorrectly - have a look at my post I've updated it. It was missing the [where argument.](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#UPDATE_rows)

Comment: Downvoted because this approach is incorrect and prone to concurrency, yielding false positives. Uniqueness is "checked" by setting up a unique key, inserting the data and catching an exception if insert fails. Selecting and checking number of rows is incorrect, by the time you receive the response another process can insert the user so you end up with two of the same. Uniqueness is NEVER checked in PHP. We have databases for a reason, they worry about the data.

Comment: Alright, how about you answer this question then? Your explanation is good, but it doesn't answer the question. I'll happily delete my answer if you do so.

Comment: How about you alter the answer based on my comment and include the example with `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` and I give you an upvote?

Comment: If I could give you 2, I would :) you deserved it. Also, regarding the amount of WP extensions that don't use the proper method - I administered a site that had maybe 1000 visits a month. On such a low volume of visits, what happened is that a similar piece of code produced two identical entries - namely, 2 admins created a category with the same name at the same time - Murphy's laws bite you when you least expect it.